# C# EPPLUS: Autosizing columns to the max autosize not working

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm generating a number of excel documents with EPPlus and I'm running into some difficulties with the formatting.

I have used

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
```

and this seems to work for the data, but does not autosize for the column names. For instance I will open up the file and I can see the column names bunched up. I can also click on the border of a column and it will expand the column more. In fact I can do this about 5 times before it seems to reach its maximum for autosizing. Essentially I want to programmatically set each column so that it's at this maximum (I've even tried applying AutoFitColumns multiple times, however this made no difference).

Is there a way to do this?

Note that I can't just hardcode the column widths as I'm trying to reuse the same code for multiple files.

EDIT: Here's my code generalised

```
private void GeneralTest()
{
    var ReportName = "myReport"
    int ReportID = 123
    var SelectedMonth = "April 2018"
    var LAGroup = "all"
    var fileName = $"{ReportName}_{SelectedMonth}_{LAGroup}.xlsx";
    // Remove all illegal characters and replace with underscores
    var[] disallowedCharacters = new[] { "/", @"\", "?", "%", "*", ":", "|", "\"", "<", ">" };
    foreach (var character in disallowedCharacters)
        fileName = fileName.Replace(character, "_");

    var filePath = $@"c:\Test\{fileName}";
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
        File.Delete(filePath);
    FileInfo NewFile = new FileInfo(filePath);

    using (ExcelPackage MyExcel = new ExcelPackage(NewFile))
    {
        var myTestdt = MyGetDataFunction(ReportID, DateTime.Parse(SelectedMonth));
        ExcelWorksheet xlWorkSheet;

        xlWorkSheet = MyExcel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Template");
        xlWorkSheet.Name = "Template";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(myTestdt, true);

        var formatRange = xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1, 1, myTestdt.Columns.Count);

        formatRange.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        formatRange.Style.Fill.PatternType = Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        formatRange.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CDFFCC"));
        formatRange.Style.Font.Size = 10;
        formatRange.Style.Font.Name = "Arial";
        formatRange.Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
        formatRange.Style.VerticalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;
        formatRange.Style.WrapText = true;

        formatRange.AutoFilter = true;

        for (int index = 0; index <= myTestdt.Columns.Count - 1; index++)
        {
            if (myTestdt.Columns(index).DataType.Name == "DateTime")
            {
                formatRange = xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, index + 1, myTestdt.Rows.Count, index + 1);
                formatRange.Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
            }
        }

        xlWorkSheet.View.FreezePanes(2, 2);

        xlWorkSheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

        MyExcel.SaveAs(NewFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: When are you calling `xlWorkSheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();`? I would call it as late as possible. All the cells should contain their final value when the AutoFitColumns method gets invoked.

Comment: I call it just before saving the document. AutoFitColumns does work... it's applying to the data fine, it's just not applying to the column names for some reason.

Comment: I am going to post an answer. It works for me.

Comment: Read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. What are "column names", exactly? And how long are they?

Comment: I've updated the question with a generalised example of my code. The column names I'm referring to are the column names of my DataTable. They vary in length from 6 characters to 50 characters

Comment: @Matt What do you mean by "column names"? Could you please post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple class I wrote to create an Excel from a DataSet.

**Please note that I intentionally avoided catching the exceptions because I do that in the caller.**

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ds2Xlsx
{

    public class Ds2ExcelEngine
    {

        public static void CreateExcel(
            DataSet ds,
            string path,
            OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles tableStyle = OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light9,
            bool autofitColumns = true)
        {
            if (ds != null)
            {
                using (ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage())
                {
                    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                    {
                        AddTableWorksheet(tableStyle, autofitColumns, ep, dt);
                    }
                    ep.SaveAs(new System.IO.FileInfo(path));
                }
            }
        }

        private static void AddTableWorksheet(OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles tableStyle, bool autofitColumns, ExcelPackage ep, DataTable dt)
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ew = ep.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(dt.TableName);
            int row = 1;
            int column = 1;
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                ew.Cells[row, column].Value = dc.Caption;
                column++;
            }

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                column = 1;
                row++;
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    ew.Cells[row, column].Value = dr[dc];
                    column++;
                }
            }

            column = 1;
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                if (dc.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    ew.Cells[1, column, row, column].Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
                }
                column++;
            }

            var excelTable = ew.Tables.Add(new ExcelAddressBase(1, 1, row, column - 1), $"tbl_{ dt.TableName }");
            excelTable.TableStyle = tableStyle;
            if (autofitColumns)
            {
                ew.Cells[ew.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I open the Excel I created, all the columns are shown correctly, either headers or content.

Comment: "It works for me in this totally unrelated code" is not an answer.

Comment: I just wanted to provide a working code sample, to show that AutoFitColumns() actually works.

Comment: I've actually already tried the ew.Cells[ew.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns(); option as well... sadly it did not work.

Comment: Then as @CodeCaster noticed, you should check what are you writing into the first row, which I assume you consider as the "column names". From the AutoFitColumns documentation:
"Set the column width from the content of the range. The minimum width is the value of the ExcelWorksheet.defaultColumnWidth property. Note: Cells containing formulas are ignored since EPPlus don't have a calculation engine. Wrapped and merged cells are also ignored."

Comment: So probably you could try and remove 
`formatRange.Style.WrapText = true;`

Comment: That's the answer PSkalka, removing WrapText fixed it. The formatting is still off, but I should be able to work with what I have now.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into almost the same problem and this did solved it for me:

`ew.Cells[ew.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();`

This does AutoFit the columns to smaller & wider when there's need for it.

Comment: Sometimes, yes.  But EPPlus has many, many properties that cause this to not happen.  I am currently having `Date & Time (UTC) of Calculation` display as `& Time (UTC) of Calcul` using auto fit